# Cannot Use my phone as emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, usb, emulation, virtual, device

I need to use my phone as emulator/virtual device when I run my application. I have installed the USB driver from SDK manager. I have enabled the USB Debugging in Settings And Updated the driver.

What more do I need to do to make Android Studio AVD Manager to detect my phone?

Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've connected the phone in "just charge" mode, and not in any other mode E.g. file transfer, MTP, etc.

Comment: I read somewhere that it should be PTP. But anyways I tried both and still not working.

Comment: Charging mode along with USB debugging enabled works for me, with no other special steps. Try disabling-enabling USB debugging or check with another cable that supports data transfer and not just charging. If it used to work previously with the same devices, try invalidating cache for Studio or reinstalling it.